# TxReceipt Status:Fail

Tags: ropsten

I was able to successfully able to deploy smart contract but the Transaction receipt status is fail. I am posting the link https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6a9f66eefaaf349043c96310879d99f02a393ff7b180962af7e856bf18c2ea1a
I think maybe there is some problem with gas price.
what should minimal gas price for an smart contract

Answer (score 3):

Without the contract code it is almost impossible to tell. But it surely has failed if you look at the contract code it is empty https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd15fe28c74975d4d4ac2167de2cf3afbac32bf89#code.

> 0x

If you examine the trace of your transaction it finish in a REVERT opcode https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x6a9f66eefaaf349043c96310879d99f02a393ff7b180962af7e856bf18c2ea1a

> [119] 86  REVERT  4527597 0   1

Both gasLimit and gasPrice seems to be ok for ropsten

> Gas Limit: 4700000
>
> Gas Price: 0.00000002 Ether (20 Gwei)

What looks odd is you sent Ether with your transaction

> Value: 10 Ether ($0.00)

It seems your constructor doesn't have the `payable` modifier. Last lines of the trace are checking the value sent in the transaction:

```
[113]   77  CALLVALUE   4527621 2   1
[114]   78  ISZERO  4527619 3   1
[115]   79  PUSH2   4527616 3   1
[116]   82  JUMPI   4527613 10  1
[117]   83  PUSH1   4527603 3   1
[118]   85  DUP1    4527600 3   1
[119]   86  REVERT  4527597 0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sample contract code for testing, you might not have a payable contract.

**Set the Ether Value to 0** might fix the issue.